# C++ line being skipped while reading a file for no reason

Tags: c++

Suppose I'm reading a file("infile.txt" to be specific) to compute the average of a quiz score. The file being read is as follows:

> Sebastian Jack 40 50 60 72 39 67 85 10 92 83
>
> Lick Dan 48 19 2 3 29 10 60 72 83 91
>
> Keng Yao 48 30 68 27 94 81 20 38 90 81
>
> Deck Hao 91 82 65 55 79 93 89 19 23 37

The output into another file is by adding another int number, which is the average of the score for each student. However, the 2nd and 4th student are being skipped for no reason. Here is the output:

> Sebastian Jack 40 50 60 72 39 67 85 10 92 83 59.8
>
> Keng Yao 48 30 68 27 94 81 20 38 90 81 57.7

Here is my code:

```
// This is a program that will output the average quiz score of all student,
based on the student score file

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream inf;
    ofstream outf;

    inf.open("infile.txt");
    outf.open("outfile.txt");

    string name;
    int score, total;
    double average;
    char next;
    while (inf >> name) {
        total = 0;

        outf << name << ' ';
        inf >> name;
        outf << name << ' ';

        while (inf >> score) {
            total += score;
            outf << score << ' ';
        }
        average = total / 10.0;
        outf << average << endl;

        inf.clear();
        inf.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    inf.close();
    outf.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any error with my code? With much thanks!

Comment: "Is there any error with my code?" Yes. Consider reading individual lines with `getline`. You have a squirrely while loop.

Comment: `ignore` is throwing away every second line. Comment that line out and it should write all the lines.

Comment: If your code works, you may want to post to CodeReviews@StackExchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function `ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` is ignoring till it gets another `'\n'` , try not using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The output file is being done correctly after i removed the code.

The reason I include the code is because initially i was just able to only read one line of the file, and I cant find the error. Then i just try to add this function to check for ''\n'' to proceed to next line.

Answer (score 4):

Jaspreet's advice is correct; I'll add some background to it.

Your program logic is one valid way to read the data. (Another possibility, often more intuitive with line-oriented "records" of data, is to read indeed line by line and parse each line individually, which makes the end of each "record" obvious.)

**Now why is `ignore()` skipping lines?** The reason is that the empty line *has already been skipped at that point.* In detail:

Your algorithm attempts to read numbers until that fails because the next word is no number (or because EOF was reached). Now the library logic for reading a number begins with skipping any leading whitespace, including newlines; you see the problem now. Only after the first letter of the next name is read does the number reading algorithm give up and puts the read letter back in the input. The skipped newlines *are not put back.* Then comes your `ignore` and skips over the valid line that we are standing at the beginning of.

The good news is that with records whose internal structure indicates record boundaries (like here: records end with a sequence of numbers; the first non-number indicates the beginning of a new record) you can ignore any white space like line breaks and just parse word by word. This makes the program more robust: You can process data with no empty lines, or with multiple empty lines, or without any line breaks at all!

If the data could conceivably contain an occasional error though (say, a letter among the numbers) the line breaks can still be used as  a spot at which re-synchronization could be attempted, in an effort of robust programming. But in your case re-synchronization would happen automatically (after reading one badly parsed "record" with a name with a number in it, probably).

As a final discussion fine point I would suggest to read from stdin and write to stdout with this type of data processing; leave the data source and destination to the caller (via `myprog < infile.txt > outfile.txt` or such). Both the Windows and *nix command lines support this. That makes the program more versatile and saves programming work. If an assignment demands the two files to be read, separate the actual *algorithmic work* on the data (parse a record and compute the average) from *obtaining and writing* the data, which should be in  a function that just gets an istream and ostream. That would make it possible to provide data from any source, for example strings, via stringstreams.

In fact, one could separate the parsing from the algorithmic work as well by defining a class which corresponds to a data record, and overload `operator>>` for it, as well as a `float record.averageScore()` member function :-). That would look more like C++.

Here are a few snippets of what might work. The `playerT`  is a class holding a "record" of data. I implemented the input function because it is somewhat tricky with clearing the input stream's fail bit.

```
/// Currently just a first name, family name and vector of scores
class playerT
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    vector<float> scores;
public:
    float averageScore() 
    { 
        return scores.size() 
                        ? accumulate(scores.begin(), scores.end(), 0.0)/scores.size() 
                        : 0; // avoid dividing by zero.
    }

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const playerT &player);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &is, playerT &player);
};

/// Produces output which could be read back with
/// the input operator. In particular, does not
/// output the average.
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const playerT &player) 
{
    //...
}

// Error handling is left to the caller.
// In particular, after EOF the player must be tested for completeness.
istream &operator>>(istream &is, playerT &player) 
{
    is >> player.firstName >> player.lastName; 

    player.scores.clear();
    float nextScore;
    while(is >> nextScore) 
    {
        player.scores.push_back(nextScore);
    }

    // Clear the expected format error indicating end of scores 
    // (and therefore this record), 
    // but not others which must be handled by the caller.
    is.clear(is.rdstate() & ~ios::failbit);
    return is;
}
```

The main function boils down to quite little, which makes the information flow clearer. The reason is that the dirty I/O details like clearing the fail bit etc. were moved to specialized functions, as well as the "business logic" of computing the average.

```
int main()
{
    do // loop to eof
    {
        playerT newPlayer;

        cin >> newPlayer;   
        // if this was the last record eof is now true
        // and the loop will exit after printing the last record.

        // todo: handle I/O errors
        cout << newPlayer << " (Av.: " << newPlayer.averageScore() << ')' << endl;
    }while(cin.good());

    return cin.bad(); // eof is ok. only bad is bad.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I already solved the problem by doing what Jaspreet suggested to do. I will read your post for further information later, since I have not learnt class and object yet.